# ArrayList columns to DataTable columns

Tags: c#, arraylist, datatable

I have an `ArrayList` which consists of multiple columns:

[image]

How do i get each value inserted into my `DataTable`?

My DataTable looks like this:

```
ArrayList crmUpdate = new ArrayList();
DataTable insertDt = new DataTable();

insertDt.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
insertDt.Columns.Add("Contractid", typeof(string));
insertDt.Columns.Add("ContractNumber", typeof(string));
insertDt.Columns.Add("InstAgreeNum", typeof(string));
insertDt.Columns.Add("ProductNumber", typeof(string));
insertDt.Columns.Add("StartDate", typeof(DateTime));
insertDt.Columns.Add("UpdatePrice", typeof(decimal));
```

Ive tried something like this:

```
foreach (object item in crmUpdate)
{
    DataRow row = insertDt.NewRow();

    row["Company"] = item;
    insertDt.Rows.Add(row);             
}
```

But i cannot get item.Company for instance. I need to know how i can reference `Item.Company` from my `ArrayList`. Hope someone can guide me further.

Thanks!

> UPDATE

Based on all the feedback - Can i do it like this then?

```
  // Calculate prices
            List<CrmPartPrice> crmUpdate = new List<CrmPartPrice>();

        foreach (CrmPartPrice item in crmUpdate)
        {
            DataRow row = insertDt.NewRow();
            row["Company"] = item.Company;
            row["Contractid"] = item.ContractId;
            insertDt.Rows.Add(row);

        }
```

Comment: Why you still need to use `ArrayList` and not `List<CrmPartPrice>`? There is no reason to use it anymore.

Comment: "I have an ArrayList..." Well there's your problem right there! unless you are working on some legacy code with .net 1.1 support, there is no need ever to use ArrayList again.

Comment: Cause im a C# newbie. Is there a difference and would it be easier to get my values ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I was just going to write its some legacy code made by a person a long time ago. Its working fine, i just need to do something else with it at the end.

Comment: @plaidDK: of course, because you don't have to cast everything in the ArrayList if you use a `List<T>`.

Comment: I hear what your saying. I will look into that at a later point when the customer accepts performance/code tuning. But for now i have to stick with this. So anyways i hope i can get some guideiance.

Comment: ArrayList can only hold `object`. This means you have to cast each item to it's actual type when you are getting it from the array list. The .Net 2.0 version introduced generics, with a bunch of collections - one of them is `List`. Using a `List` means you store the items in their original type, and you don't need to cast them.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks. I just have to correct this many places so I cant do that now. But i would def look into that at a later point.

Comment: @plaidDK: don't wait for customer feedback. Change it now. It's as easy as: `var crmUpdate=new List<CrmPartPrice>()`. You should also change the parameter type to `List<CrmPartPrice>`.

Comment: Use following : insertDt.Rows.Add(partsArray.ToArray());

Comment: @TimSchmelter I justed updated my Question. Is that what you meant? If it is then you just made me much more clever today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the `ArrayList` to a `List<T>` for some reason, you will need to cast the items from the `ArrayList` to their actual types, since `ArrayList` stores everything as `object`:

```
foreach (object item in crmUpdate)
{
    // the item reference is of type `object`, cast it to CrmPartPrice
    var partPrice = (CrmPartPrice)item; 
    var row = insertDt.NewRow();

    row["Company"] = partPrice.Company;
    row["Contractid"] = partPrice.Contractid;
    // more of the same...
    insertDt.Rows.Add(row);             
}
```

However, you should probably change the `ArrayList` into a proper `List`, and since they share a lot of methods, it might be just a matter of changing the declaration from `ArrayList crmUpdate = new ArrayList();` to `var crmUpdate = new List<CrmPartPrice>`, as Tim Schmetler suggested in his comment.

Comment: Thanks - Just out of curious - How would it look like if i had a List? Not that you should solve my problem, but it would be nice for me in the future. If you have the time. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you see my update - Can you verify thats what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Woohu - Thanks for your advices! Have a great sunny day.

Comment: Glad to help :-) you too!